# Xcode 7.2 Interface Builder high CPU sluggish slow

Tags: interface-builder, xcode7

`Interface Builder` freezes when I add a `UIView` with a `UILabel` in place of the `title`

I have tried disabling `Autolayout`, removed `Storyboard` reference from the project and add it back again.

[image: Activity Monitor shot]

Mac info:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the answer here, but I have been strugling with this problem for a while with Xcode 8 in El capitan having this same issue.

I take no credit for the solution, it goes to sroebert user in apple forums, you can see the original source [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66551) (you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> his username to get to his answer).

In my case, the problem presented only in specific nibs, not every nib nor storyboard. For my surprise, changing the `Top Bar` from `Opaque Navigation Bar` to `Inferred` made Xcode and Interface builder responsive once again.

It may or may not help you, but I hope it helps someone.

[image: Top bar simulated metrics]

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. It's ridiculous that this is the solution but then xcode is getting more ridiculous by the day.